# Merge Google Accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-account

I have a Google Apps Account which has recently been changed to a full Google Account which has the email address me@mydomain.com . I also have a gmail account with me@gmail.com . The Gmail account has stuff stored in Google Calendar, and is linked to a YouTube account. The Google Apps account has Google Analytics in use, and Google Docs. Both accounts have Google Reader in use.

Is it possible to fully merge these two accounts? At the moment, the Gmail account just forwards all email to Google Apps account, but I would like to have the Calendar and YouTube accounts also under the one account.

If not, is there a way to migrate my calendar data to the Google Apps account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Google's support docs, [it's not possible to merge accounts](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304).

They do offer a comprehensive list of [how to move and share data between Google accounts](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582).  For the specific products you mention:

- Google Reader can export feeds from one account and import to another
- Calendars can be shared; if you have meeting invites being forwarded via email you should be able to accept them on the new account.
- It is possible to unlink a YouTube account (by [visiting this webpage](http://www.youtube.com/my_account_unlink)) from one Google account and re-link it to another (by [visiting this other webpage](http://www.youtube.com/finish_link_upgrade)).

Comment: Too bad, I got the message "Your youtube has been linked to your google account permanently"