# How to merge google account with google for domain account?

Tags: google-workspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge Google Accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8754/merge-google-accounts)

Before google integrated all of their services, I had a separate Google account for Latitude, Maps, and Voice (Gmail a).  I also had a google for domain account (gmail b).  Now that they have finally integrated everything, I have all of those services connected to my google domain account, but I lost everything associated with my original account.

Is it possible to migrate information / data from Latitude, Maps, Voice to my new one and entirely blow away the old?  Another oddity with my account is that if I make a call through gmail (for my domain), it uses my original gmail google voice account and not the one that it is currently linked to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is mostly "no".  Data can only be moved for certain Google services.  The services that can be moved directly to another account are: AdWords, Blogger, FeedBurner, Picasa Web Albums, Reader, and YouTube.  (For the most recent list from Google, see this link: http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=58582 )  Some of the other services (such as Reader) can be moved by exporting the settings from the old account and importing them into the new one.

You're not the only person with this issue.  I have to maintain two separate Google accounts now, as well, and it can be fairly annoying.  You'll want to turn on the "Multiple sign-in" option under 'My account".  I've found that Google Voice still always defaults to the wrong account, and I have to switch to it using 'Switch account' option each time I log in (look in the upper-right, click on your e-mail address after enabling Multiple sign-in).

Your Google Voice number **can** be moved to the new Google account, though.  Fill out this form (it took them a few days to do it when I requested the move): http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1378061